# Donkey Kong Country: Tropical Freeze 6-5: Forest Folly

Tags: donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze

I'm playing the Switch version of DKCTF and I'm completely stuck on 6-5. After the first checkpoint, I no matter what I do, Donkey Kong slides off the first grass platform before I can ground pound and send him to the next one. I've tried jumping, but that doesn't seem to help.

I've lost about 40 lives on this one section so far, and I have no idea what I'm supposed to be doing. When I watch videos of others playing the level online, this doesn't seem to be an issue.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEmB3.jpg) a video of the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's grass that you can grab and hold on to (like the sections where you dangle from the ceiling). Press the R Button to grab and hold onto the grass. Once you are holding down the R button press the Y Button to ground pound and launch off of it like a spring.

Comment: This answer has actually helped me in 6-3. I guess these grass sections without banana trails, and with ice themes, are relatively hard to identify visually... Will keep a heads-up in next levels!